# Sharing files between Ubuntu VM on Windows Server Host

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

On a corporate Windows 2008 Enterprise server I do not have physical access to, I have been attempting to get an Ubuntu VM setup.

The Ubuntu VM is setup and working.  The problem I have right now, is until I can install a set of corporate security compliance tools on Ubuntu, I can't get any internet access to it.  Any guide or information I've found on sharing files between the Windows Server and the Ubuntu VM always ends up where I would need network access so that Ubuntu can download package ("failed to download package files...").

With the Ubuntu VM not able to download package files right now, would anyone know how I could simply get access in any way to the share folder I setup or any other method of getting software package files over to the Ubuntu VM so that I can get it corporate compliant and on the network?

On the Windows server itself, I have already downloaded all the corproate security packages I need to install.  I just can't figure out how I can share the files to the Ubuntu server so that I can install them.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to follow [these setup instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713111/how-to-share-a-folder-between-win10-and-ubuntu-installed-with-vmware-12/952907#952907). However, you need the Open VM Tools to be installed, and this may require internet access. So you got some sort of chicken-egg situation here. Maybe you'll find a way to provide it via ISO media.